# Non-static data member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Are there any differences between the following three structure definitions according to the C++ standard?

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
};

struct Foo
{
    int a{};
};

struct Foo
{
    int a{0};
};
```

The last two are C++11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the first definition, if you create an instance of `Foo` with automatic storage duration, `a` will be uninitialized. You can perform aggregate initialization to initialize it.

```
Foo f{0};  // a is initialized to 0
```

The second and third definitions of `Foo` will both initialize the data member `a` to `0`.

In C++11, neither 2 nor 3 are [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/241631), but C++14 [changes that rule](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html) so that they both remain aggregates despite adding the *brace-or-equal-initializer*.

Comment: FYI, there is a [what changed in C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27511360/1708801) which covers that issue in your first link.

Comment: @Shafik I hadn't seen your addition to that answer, it's nice to have all the info in the same place.

Comment: I figured, it is a long scroll down. I only noticed that the addition was needed because R. Martinho Fernandes added a bounty looking for a C++14 answer.

Comment: @Praetorian : Similar question, but instead of the non-static member variable, If I create the object for the first struct like this - Foo foo{}, then "int a" would be 0 initialized. why ?

Comment: @PabitraPadhy Yes, `a` will be 0 because it's value initialized. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
}bar;
```

bar.a is uninitialized if not in global scope or not-static.

```
struct Foo
{
    int a{};
}bar;
```

bar.a is initialized to `0`

```
struct Foo
{
    int a{0};
}bar;
```

bar.a is initialized to `0`

So constructs 2 and 3 are same. 1 is different.

For more details, you may want to read [Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and [Class Member Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

Comment: 2 and 3 are not same, even though they do the same thing in *this* case.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks. I agree with you and do think the same. My point was, in OP's case, empty brace list and a brace list with `0` would exhibit same observable effect.

Answer (score 1):

First one is POD type. Member `a` is initialized by 0.